# Macの通信状態を調べたい

Tags: macos, network

Macがどこと通信をしているか調べる方法はありますか?
ターミナルなどを使う操作でも良いのでおしえてください。

例えばスカイプを起動している時に通信しているサーバーや送信情報など。

Answer (score 5):

## 前置き

### アクティビティモニタ

プリインストールされているものでいえば、ユーティリティフォルダの「アクティビティモニタ」が使えます。
起動して、通信状況を確認したいアプリケーションの名称をダブルクリック（または ⌘-I）し、表示されるウィンドウで「開いているファイルとポート」タブを選択して暫く待つと、アプリケーションが開いているファイルのリスト、そして末尾の方にポート及び通信先IPアドレスなどが表示されます。

- [See What Files & Ports an Application is Using with Activity Monitor](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/05/see-what-files-ports-an-application-is-using-with-activity-monitor/)

ただし。
非常に読みづらいです。

### ネットワークユーティリティ

通信と言えば Netstat 。ユーティリティフォルダには以前 Netstat を含む「ネットワークユーティリティ」があったはずなのですが…と思って Spotlight で探してみると見つかりました。今（ Mavericks 以降）は `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/` 以下にあります。

> 各ツールとその使い方についてもっと詳しく知りたい場合は、ネットワークユーティリティを開いて「ヘルプ」メニューの「ネットワークユーティリティ・ヘルプ」を選択します。

- [OS X：ネットワークユーティリティについて - Apple サポート](http://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT5897)

しかし。
Netstat って各アプリケーションには関連しないのですね、忘れていましたorz

### Wireshark

パケットキャプチャしたいならばもちろん Wireshark がベストだと思います。しかし、インストールが面倒で、しかも機能が多すぎて使いづらい。通信内容を確認したいならばともかく、何がどこと通信してるか程度を知りたいときに Wireshark を使うのは大げさです。

## 本編

先ほど引用した [See What Files & Ports an Application is Using with Activity Monitor](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/05/see-what-files-ports-an-application-is-using-with-activity-monitor/) で

> The data is presented a little rough, if you want an easier to browse version of open network connections take a look at the free GUI tool [PrivateEye](https://radiosilenceapp.com/private-eye).

というコメントが載っていました。
私もこれで初めて知ったアプリケーションなのですが、これはかなり便利です。

- [Private Eye | Free Network Monitor for Mac](https://radiosilenceapp.com/private-eye)

[image: screenshot_b.png (968×636)]

通信状況が時刻とアプリケーション名と通信先（名前解決できればURLで、できなければIPアドレスで）表示されます。そして表示項目は時刻・アプリケーション・通信先でソート出来ます。また通信は、全て、受信、送信、もしくはアプリケーションを指定して表示することが出来ます。

## 結論

Private Eye 、お勧めです。
（ただ、 <del>送信</del> 受信がキャプチャ出来てるのか、少し気に掛かります。 <del>受信</del> 送信しか表示されない…）

Answer (score 4):

ターミナル(コマンドライン)で使うのでしたら、`lsof` コマンドが適当ではないかと思います(あるいは `netstat`)。ただし、通信先だけで通信内容を表示する機能はありません。

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:ESTABLISHED
mplayer  1466 nemo 1007u  IPv4 1668456      0t0  TCP nemo:39041->pub5.jazzradio.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 19140 nemo   35u  IPv4 1658292      0t0  TCP nemo:50422->r-100-00-000-00.twttr.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 19140 nemo   60u  IPv4 1669084      0t0  TCP nemo:42877->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome  20695 nemo  108u  IPv4 1696820      0t0  TCP nemo:53326->hogeXXsYY-in-fT.1ex00.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
mplayer 20778 nemo 1007u  IPv4 1668456      0t0  TCP nemo:39041->pub5.jazzradio.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

`lsof` のオプションについては `man lsof` でご確認下さい。  
通信内容も知りたい場合は、、まぁ、それなりのモノを使えば良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

GUIで細かいところまで知りたいのであれば、Windowsと同様にWiresharkを利用すればいいかと思います。
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

動かすまでが面倒なので、この辺りを参考に・・・
http://blog.pg1x.com/entry/2014/07/08/231557

Answer (score 2):

Wiresharkで通信先を確認するのが良いかと思います。
下記に手順を記載します。

X11をダウンロードし、インストール

```
http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
```

Wiresharkをダウンロードし、インストール。

```
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html
```

X11の格納先を聞かれた場合

```
/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app
```

に格納されているので、指定する。

インターフェースへのアクセス権を設定

```
sudo chmod 0644 /dev/bpf*
```

キャプチャするインターフェースeth0などを指定し、
startボタンを押下で、該当インターフェースでの通信ログを取得することができます。
[image: インターフェース追加設定画面]